# JSX inside Javascript inside JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to use JSX expression as a part of generated body of another JSX expression:

```
render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {[...Array(5).keys()].map(i => <tr>{
          [...Array(7).keys()].map(j => <td>{
            i * j + (<span>{i + j}</span>)
          }</td>)
        }</tr>)}
      </table>
    )
}
```

The `i * j` part renders correctly, but `(<span>{i + j}</span>)` renders as `[object Object]`. How can I fix it or how can I make it work in another way?

Comment: Functions would make this so much simpler

Answer (score 1):

You can't return tags from within `{}`. Try:

```
render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {[...Array(5).keys()].map(i => <tr>{
          [...Array(7).keys()].map(j => <td>
            {i * j}
            <span>{i + j}</span>
          </td>)
        }</tr>)}
      </table>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with JSX but with the expression `{i * j + (<span>{i + j}</span>)`. The `<span>{i + j}</span>` part will be converted to an object. You're actually trying to append and object to a number which turns out like this:

`1 + {} => 1.toString() + {}.toString() => "1[object Object]"`

I'm not sure what you're trying to render but if you want to append the `i * j` part to the `span` you need to put them in an array or just wrap the `i * j` in braces and leave the `span` tag in pure JSX instead of using the plus operator.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
          <table>
            {[...Array(5).keys()].map(i => (<tr>{[...Array(7).keys()].map(j => (<td>{i*j}<span>{i + j}</span></td>))
            }</tr>))}
          </table>
        )

  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

put your expression `i*j` inside `{}`, not `span`

```
render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {[...Array(5).keys()].map(i => <tr>{
          [...Array(7).keys()].map(j => <td>{i * j}<span>{i + j</span</td>)
        }</tr>)}
      </table>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap `span` in `{}`

```
<table>
  {[...Array(5).keys()].map(i => (
    <tr>{ [...Array(7).keys()].map(j => (
      <td>
        {i * j} <span>{i + j}</span>
      </td>
     )
    )}
    </tr>
  )
  )}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {[...Array(5).keys()].map(i => <tr>{
          [...Array(7).keys()].map(j => <td>
            {i * j}+
            <span>{i + j}</span>
          }</td>)
        }</tr>)}
      </table>
    )
}
```